# Will Windows Phone 8 support Qt?

Tags: qt, windows-phone-8

I'm just wondering, if the native app development support is now introduced to Windows phone 8, does this mean that we can -technically- develop Qt-based app and benefit from the QML technology?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is a lengthy technical report on the feasibility of supporting Qt on Windows 8 here:

http://qt-project.org/wiki/Qt-5-on-Windows-8-and-Metro-UI

From the conclusions it sounds quite feasible.

Comment: With some notable exceptions introduced by the political limitations of the WinRT model ("We estimate at least 10 to 15 man-days of further research is needed to determine if ANGLE on WinRT is feasible. If investigation finds that this is feasible, the effort is expected to be significant.").

Comment: yes, feasible - but quite a lot of effort required. I still think that is a pretty positive message.

Comment: I find it rather unlikely. And QML is a horrible horrible way to build UIs compared to XAML. And lets not start talking about lack of standard controls, performance, and so on.

Comment: @ClausJørgensen-MSFT so horrible that C#/Mono people praise it: https://twitter.com/migueldeicaza/statuses/2455228032
https://blogs.kde.org/2012/06/06/de-icaza-were-dropping-xaml-qmls-human-friendly
Compare by yourself: http://www.developer.nokia.com/community/wiki/Animation_Basics_Silverlight_vs._QML

Answer (score 6):

A bit of an update to this old question, links:

- [Building Qt 5 for Windows 8 Modern UI (Windows Store Apps & Windows Phone 8)](http://qt-project.org/wiki/WinRTBuild)
- [Building and deploying your WinRT apps (Tech Preview 1)](http://qt-project.org/wiki/WinRT_TP1_deployment)
- Qt5 documentation snapshot: [WinRT](http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/qt5-dev/winrt-support.html)

So to answer the question: **Yes**, it's indeed technically possible. Still (start of 2014) in early stages of development, so everything does not work, project set up is clumsy etc, but looks pretty promising. No idea about when official out-of-the-box support might come to Qt 5 SDK, but Qt is open source, so you can start playing with it already.